# Which parameters decide the performance of video online/watching websites?

Tags: performance, video, web

I am new in web developer. I wanted to know about the performance of video in web. My question is Which parameters decide the performance of video online/watching websites? anybody can tell.

Answer (score 0):

When you're streaming video over a network connection, there are two main reasons why a video might perform poorly: network and computing power.  Either the network couldn't retrieve the data in time, or the computer the browser is running on couldn't decode and render it fast enough.  The former is much more common.

The major properties of a video that would affect this:

1. **Bitrate**:
   Expressed in Kbps or Mbps, most people think this is a measurement of quality, but it's not.  Rather, bitrate is a measurement of how much data is used to represent a second of video.  A larger bitrate means a bigger file for the same runtime, and assuming limited bandwidth, this is the single most important factor in determining how your video will perform.
2. **Codec**:
   The codec refers to the specific algorithm used to encode and compress moving picture data into bits. The main features affected are file size and video quality, (which in turn affects the bitrate), but some codecs are also more challenging to render than others, leading to poor performance on an older or burdened system even when the network bandwidth isn't an issue.  Again, note that a video requiring too much network is much more common than a video requiring too much computer.

For the end user who is watching the video, there are a few factors that are not part of the videos themselves that can impact performance:

3. **The network**:
   Obviously, a user has to have a certain amount of bandwidth consistently available to stream video at a given quality level, so they won't be able to play much while downloading from a fast server or running Tor, but the server also needs to be able to deliver the bits to everyone who's asking for them.  The quality level of the video that can play without stuttering can be drastically reduced by network congestion, disparity in geographical location between the client and the server, denial of service (i.e., things not responding), or any other factor that keeps all the viewers from retrieving bits consistently as the video plays.  This is a tough challenge, and there's a whole industry of Content Delivery Networks (CDNs) devoted to the problem of how to deliver a large amount of data can get to a large number of people in many different places on the globe as fast as possible.
4. **Their computer/device**:
   As codecs have gotten more advanced, they've been able to do better, more complex math to turn pictures into bits.  This has made file sizes smaller and quality higher, but it's also made the videos more computationally expensive to decode.  Turning bits back into video takes horsepower, and older computers, less powerful devices, and systems that are just doing too much at the moment may be unable to decode video delivered at a certain bitrate.

There are a few other video properties relevant to performance, but mostly these end up affecting the bitrate.  Resolution is an example of this: a video encoded at a native resolution of 1600x900 will be harder to stream than a video encoded at 320x240, but since the higher resolution takes up more space (i.e., requires more bits) to store than the lower resolution does for the same length of video, the difference ends up being reflected in the bitrate.

The same is true of file size: it doesn't really matter how big the file is in total; the important number is the bitrate -- the amount of space/bandwidth one second of video takes up.

I think those are the major factors that determine whether a certain video will perform well for a particular user requesting from a specific computer at a given network location.